# How to write a script that will open up multiple tabs in the terminal?

Tags: shell-script, osx, terminal-emulator

I am on OSX and using iTerm

I have this so far

```
#!/bin/sh

open /Applications/iTerm.app &

exit 0
```

So after opening, I need two windows and one of those windows will need to open 6 tabs. two of those tabs will need to enter into a certain directory, one of those needs to run an app like

```
cd ~/Desktop/projects/myNodeApp
node app.js
```

Comment: Check out the documentation at Sourceforge here, http://iterm.sourceforge.net/scripting.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Applescript like so:

```
on run args
    set home to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) as string
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        set myTerm to (make new terminal)
        tell myTerm
            repeat with i from 1 to 6
                set newTab to (make new session at the end of sessions)
                tell newTab
                    set name to "My tab " & i
                    exec command "/bin/bash"
                    write text "cd " & home & "/Desktop/projects/myNodeApp"
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: This worked fine. except for running the node app. I added `write text "node app.js"` but then got the error `bash: node: command not found`

Comment: Maybe no `$PATH` is set. Try specifying the full path to node, e.g., `/usr/bin/node`